# Tag Cloud server control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, tag-cloud

Is there a Tag Cloud server control for ASP.NET that can satisfy theese requirements:

- font size calculation formula from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud)
- just href rendering, no javascript needed
- css classes for all font sizes used in cloud

I know that I can build it myself ;) and quite easly but I am lazy and maybe there is a nice implementation with such reqs.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Amazing Tag Cloud](http://tagcloud.codeplex.com/) control on Codeplex.

You could always customize the source code to satisfy your requirements (better than writing from scratch).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, holy grail of Tag cloud controls, it's awesome

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tagcloud/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx